# Is there a sensible way for letting Primefaces Datatables remember sorting

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have an application with a prime faces datatable with several columns. The user clicks on the heading of one of the columns so the column is sorted in ascending or descending order (Maybe column "firstname" in "descending order").

Now the user clicks on another page. Later, he returns back to the page with the data table.

Is there a sensible way, so that automatically the sorting state (here "firstname descending") is restored, so the user does not have to click the heading of the column again?

With "sensible" I mean, that cumbersome and error-prone workarounds should be avoided.

Comment: did you think saving the user setting in a sort of @applicationScope managedBean ?!?

Comment: Similarly. I thought about a @SessionScoped managedBean.

Comment: Yeah it's true that this scoped is different but in our case it will be just pretty the same, would like to go the the chat to speak about this subject ???

Comment: Im am new to StackOverflow, so I don't know, how the chat works.

Comment: This is my first question, so I don't have 20 reputation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read What topics can I ask about and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have read that. Is something wrong?

Comment: non every thing ok i will give an answer about your question

Comment: Go for PrimeFaces Elite (or wait for 6.1). It is built-in there

Comment: @Kukeltje why not working with abstract class and extend it ?!?

Comment: Sure you can, I currently do it like that to. But am switching to the built-in way since it saves code...  The built-in solution (re)stores pagination, sorting, filter and selection http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=4216 and  Column Order, Width and Visibility and Expanded Rows in the coming versions.